Power Automate: IF condition in column of "Add a row into a table" triggered from a MS form
I've created a flow in Power Automate to add a new row to a spreadsheet.  The issue I'm having is that for one column I need to say what system the form submission relates to.  Since I only have one system currently, I just want to put in an expression that will say IF System Login is not blank then put "Master" Field list
I've put this expression against the 'Which system does this relate to?' field but although it doesn't error, the spreadsheet isn't populating.
if(not(empty(triggerOutputs()?['body/resourceData/System login'])),'Master','')
All the other fields are working fine, but they're just direct input from the form so I wouldn't expect there to be an issue.  I've made sure when testing that there's a value in the 'System login' field when submitting the form as well but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.
I've tried this:
if(not(empty(triggerOutputs()?['body/resourceData/System login'])),'Master','')
and some variations before this - e.g. System_login, system login and system_login in case it was case sensitive or did/didn't like the space.
There's no error messages that appear, but the value is blank
Can anyone help with this please?

You are not accessing the output correctly. Your expression should be:
if(not(empty(triggerOutputs()?['body']?['resourceData']?['System login'])),'Master','')


I've tried your suggestion and used a test word 'Empty' instead of just being blank so I could be sure that it was doing something.  My test submissions went through to my spreadsheet but all the answers seem to be showing 'Empty' whether I answer the 'System Login' question or if I just leave it blank.  I'm thinking that I may have to use a condition instead.

you could also put the if(not(empty...))) in a compose action to see whether it is returning true or false to debug. You could also do the same for the output to see how it is being populated
